# Authentication failure while using nestjs authentication

Tags: typescript, authentication, jwt, express-jwt, nestjs

I am trying to implement authentication using nestjs documentation.
https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/authentication

And I am implementing JWT Authentication and when trying to access an API which is being authenticated, I am getting validation error, even before validating. Has anyone faced similar issue.

```
@Get()
  @UseGuards(AuthGuard('jwt'))
  async findAll(): Promise<UserDto[]> {
    return this.userService.findAll();
  }
```

This route is giving me UnAuthorized error. I am really new to Typescript and nestjs

My code is available here in my GitHub repo. Please let me know what went wrong.
https://github.com/shamnadps/TypeScript_Project/blob/master/src/user/user.controller.ts#L23

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your - slight but critical - error resides in the `secretOrKey` value you're using to sign your token. You have different values between **`src/auth/jwt.strategy.ts`** and **`src/auth/auth.service.ts`**.

In `src/auth/auth.service.ts`:
Instead of this:

```
async createToken() {
    const user: UserDto = { name: 'shamnad', phoneNumber: '12435' };
    return jwt.sign(user, 'secretkey'); // <== /!\ focus on this one /!\
}
```

Use this:

```
async createToken() {
        const user: UserDto = { name: 'shamnad', phoneNumber: '12435' };
        return jwt.sign(user, 'secretKey'); // <== /!\ focus on this one /!\
}
```

Because you use **`secretKey`** to sign your token, and not *`secretkey`* (notice the camel case):

```
constructor(private readonly authService: AuthService) {
    super({
      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
      secretOrKey: 'secretKey', // <== /!\ focus on this line /!\
    });
}
```

To avoid such problems, I'd recommend you to use *`process.env.<your-variable>`* instead of directly setting config manually in strings.

---

It would look something like this in `src/auth/jwt.strategy.ts`:

```
constructor(private readonly authService: AuthService) {
    super({
      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
      secretOrKey: process.env.SECRET
    });
}
```

and in `src/auth/auth.service.ts`, like this:

```
async createToken() {
    const user: UserDto = { name: 'shamnad', phoneNumber: '12435' };
    return jwt.sign(user, process.env.SECRET); // <== /!\ focus on this one /!\
}
```

Finally, to set the environment variable, execute the following command based on your OS:
- Mac OS: `export SECRET=<your-secret-key>`
- Windows: `set SECRET=<your-secret-key>`

I hope it helps ;)

Comment: yes this was it!. Thank you for your time on looking into my code. I had already found it yesterday. But Thanks a lot for your time and effort.

Answer (score 0):

how did you access the route?

you must create the token first.

don't know if this gives you a hint

[image]

Comment: Yes, I created a token and then send it as Authorization header using post man. still didn't work.